# Complexity Analysis Pseudocode Snippet

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, analysis, pseudocode

I have a question concerning a question on a past paper (my school does not provide me solutions for them). I was wondering if I've done the question correctly:

Let X be an array with the elements X(1),...,X(n) such that each X(i) is an integer satisfying 0≤X(i)≤n^2 , let Y be an array with the elements Y(1),...,Y(n) such that each Y(i) is an integer satisfying 1≤Y(i)≤n^4 , and let Z be an integer variable with the value satisfying 1≤Z≤n. Then consider the following fragment of code:

```
for i := 1 to Z do
    for j := n*n - X(i) to Y(i)*Y(i) + n*n do
        k := 0
```

Analyse the complexity of this code in the best case and worst case, counting 1 unit for each basic operation, and expressing the total count as a function of n.

Here is my approach:

For the worst case, I have let `Z = n`, `every Y(i) = n^4` and `every X(i) = 0`. I am trying to get the loops to iterate around the most times within the worst case. I think these values would be what would be needed during the worst case - so for my analysis I have gotten the function `T(n) = 2n^5 + 2n + 1` as the first line is `n+1`, the second is `(n^4 + 1)n` and the final line of pseudocode is `n^5`

For the best case I have let `Z = 1`, `every X(i) = 0` and every `Y(i) = 1`

Thus I got the function `T(n) = 7` as the first line executes twice, the second thrice, and the third line twice. I am unsure if this is right, I am counting the for loop checking if i has exceeded the value (hence the extra addition of 1 to the complexity of for loop lines).

Is my complexity analysis right, or am I approaching this completely incorrectly/have major misconception or errors in my working out. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me, although with big-O analysis, it's easier to just say `O(n^5)` and `O(1)`. Easier to think in big-O terms as well and not bother with the exact form. Unless that is what you were asked to do.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I am pretty sure we are expected to give the function as the exact form (or as close to exact as we were taught in class) - if this was in my exam I'd probably include the big O form as well to the side of the page.

Comment: Is the posted code wrong, or are you missing the fact that `Y(i)*Y(i)` is potentially as large as `n^8`, giving a total complexity of `n^9`? The inner loop iterates potentially `n^8+n^2` times (when `Y(i) == n^4` and `X(i) == 0`)... Best case would be when `X(i) == 0` and `Y(i) == 1`, yielding a single iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: Ahh, you're right, the evaluation there is meant to be `n^8` I was jumping the gun whilst I was calculating this on paper. Thanks for pointing that out! I also missed out the `+ n^2` part but do you mean (for the worst case) that `Y(i) == n^4` and `X(i) = n^2` opposed to `X(i) = 0`.

Comment: @TomHower Yes... that's correct... Worst case would be from 0 to `n^8+n^2` in the inner loop; best would be from `n^2` to `1 + n^2`... Since we're talking about complexity analysis, for sufficiently large `n`, `n^8 + n^2 ~= n^8`, so it would be normal to drop the `n^2` term in the final analysis...